# How to mock a ref in jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

My useState

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>(
    accordionRef.current?.scrollHeight ? accordionRef.current?.scrollHeight : 0,
);
```

My Ref

```
const accordionRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

A snippet of the code where I use the Ref

```
<WrapperAccordion>
  <WrapperFlexButtonStrength>
    <WrapperButtonStrength>
      <Button
        fullWidth
        handleClick={() => handleOpenAccordion()}
        text="my label"
        typeButton="tertiary"
       />
     </WrapperButtonStrength>
  </WrapperFlexButtonStrength>
  <WrapperStrengthMeter
     ref={accordionRef}
     height={height}
     data-is-open={openAccordion}
  >
     <InfoPasswordStrength
        contains={password.contains}
        length={password.length}
        minLength={minLength}
      />
  </WrapperStrengthMeter>
</WrapperAccordion>
```

I need to return this mocado value from the ref, but I can't.

```
accordionRef.current?.scrollHeight
```

I'm using React version 18, styled-components and @testing-library/jest-dom version 5.16.4

Can anyone help?

My test not coverage accordionRef.current?.scrollHeight

```
it("should render", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout");

    render(<Wrapper />);

    const button = screen.getByRole("button", {
      name: "my label",
    });

    fireEvent.click(button);
    await fireEvent.click(button);
});
```